# NoClassDefFound: org/apache/tools/ant/util/ReaderInputStream

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a java project in Intellij with gradle. It worked until a few hours ago, but suddenly after minor changes (or so I think) I get an error:

```
Error:gradle-resources-test:analyzer_main: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/ant/util/ReaderInputStream
```

It is a missing ant dependency, but my project doesn't use ant.
I did upgrade Intellij yesterday, to 2018.1.3 community edition. Invalidate caches/restart doesn't help, closing and opening project doesn't help, re-defining the module doesn't help.

I have to similar projects, that don't have the issue in the same instance of Intellij IDEA.

What do I do to fix this?

Comment: I fixed it by taking directories "gradle" and .gradle and file gradlew from another project and put them in my project. This replaced gradle 2.1 by 4.2, I don't know how come the broken project had an old version of gradle. I did this after deleting the project and checking it out from git again.